# How to make a circle around a letter?

Tags: html, css

I need to make a small circle background behind the letter "A". What CSS would make this effect?

See example:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With CSS? Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/eLhqswyd/

```css
.i-circle {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 30px; /* set to same size as width, height */
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="i-circle">i</span>
<span class="i-circle">w</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this has been answered years ago, still:

To make a circle around the text you can use padding like the previous answer.

```css
span{
  background: red;
  padding: .5rem .85rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span>i</span><span>m</span>
```

But as you can see, it won't circle all the letters *(m)*. To make any letter have a circle background, you can use fixed height and width. And then use flexbox/grid/absolute-position to center the text, like this:

```css
span{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-flex; /* you can also use 'grid' or just 'flex'*/
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span>i</span><span>m</span><span>A</span>
```